# Streaming Real and Debug Data To Disk in C++

Tags: c++, matlab, logging, hdf5

What is a flexible way to stream data to disk in a c++ program in Windows?

I am looking to create a flexible stream of data that may contain arbitrary data (say time, average, a flag if reset, etc) to disk for later analysis. Data may come in at non-uniform, irregular intervals. Ideally this stream would have minimal overhead and be easily readable in something like MATLAB so I could easily analyze events and data.

I'm thinking of a binary file with a header file describing types of packets followed by a wild dump of data tagged with . I'm considering a lean, custom format but would also be interested in something like [HDF5](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/whatishdf5.html).

Comment: Have you consider something like the [MAT-file format](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/matfile_format.pdf) (PDF warning)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably better to use an existing file format rather than a custom one. First you don't reinvent the wheel, second you will benefit from a well tested and optimized library.

HFD5 seems like a good bet. It is fast and reliable, and easy to read from Matlab. It has some overhead but it is to allow great flexibility and compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

This requirement sounds suspiciously like a "database"